# By what ways can I seek attention of my friends to explore business oppotunities?

Tags: conversations, friends, business

We are 4 close friends and all are well settled and prosper. I am initiating business proposals among us but the problem is none of them takes the conversation seriously. However, they all say that they will start any business in near time but not paying attention to look for a business opportunity according to our tier 2 city and never initiating any discussion from their side.

From my view, they are just thinking of doing a business in the future because they are satisfied with their job's pay scale.

What should I do so that they could pay attention and start to explore opportunities by having a conversation on this particular topic?

Comment: Have you suggested any specific business proposals where you and your friends could take immediate action, or just general ideas for types of businesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that they don't take the conversations seriously may be that they don't seriously want to start a business at the moment.

One thing to keep in mind is that starting and maintaining a business is difficult and stressful and if done with friends can tear apart your friendships.  Carefully consider if your pursuit of a business opportunity is worth losing your friends.

You can continue to present the idea, but until they are serious about it you can't expect them to jump into a business opportunity just because you bring up the topic.  And even if you do get them on board, you will always risk destroying the friendships.